# Default creation of has_one dependency in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to understand best practices for creating a dependency of a model in rails. The scenario is simple. The two models are:

```
class Main < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_one :dependent
    validates :dependent, presence: true
end

class Dependent < ActiveRecord::Base 
end
```

(Note that I want to validate to ensure the dependent always exists)

Whenever a `Main` object is created I want a `Dependent` object to be created and "default initialized". I come from a background of C++ hence I view this problem as one of constructing a member variable whose type is some `class` which has a default constructor.

There are a bunch of ways I can solve this.

1. Put logic in `before_validation` to create a `Dependent`.

This feels very "un-railsy". I wanted to do this in `before_create` but validations are done before that callback. Doing it in `before_validation` is ugly as this callback is called both on create *and* on update, which makes the logic tricky/messy.

2. Put logic in `.new`

This feels very *very* "un-railsy" and is probably conceptually wrong. I'd see `new` as performing `ActiveRecord` construction which happens before the model is built.

3. Make the caller do the work

Whenever a `Main` object is created it must be done via `new-save` rather than `create`. The calling code then has to create `Dependent` itself, albeit with default values, e.g.

```
Main.new do |m|
    m.dependent = Dependent.create
end
```

This is annoyingly burdensome on callers and causes a lot of duplicate code. I could pack this into a factory type method but the same problem exists that calling code needs to do some legwork.

Is there a canonical solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `after_create` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M002142) and create Dependent instance in this method.

Comment: This does not work for the same reason that `before_create` doesn't work. Validations are called *before* `after_create`. So in order to use this I would need to remove my validation `validates :dependent, presence: true`. I don't want to do this because the validation is genuinely needed. I want to ensure that the dependent is never set to `nil` when the `Main` object is updated.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Glad you found what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I found a callback I hadn't see listed before: `after_initialize`. I can do what I want here.

A note for others:

My particular case is quite straightforward as I always want my dependent class to be default initialized *and* the user doesn't ever need to set anything. However, in a more complex situation this wouldn't work and initializing dependents may require:

1. Explicit initialization at the site of creation
2. UI for user to initialize the dependent using `#accepts_nested_attributes_for`